# Size a background image?

Tags: html, css, background

I have a div that is 200px by 200px.

It's background image is 500px x 500px.

Is there a way to make sure the entire background image fits into the div? I know you can size it with CSS3 but i'm looking for a solution for older browsers.

Thanks

Comment: the image already has an aspect ratio of 1:1. What's stoping you from resizing the image in photoshop?

Comment: What Jawad said. But if you do need to dynamically resize the image on the fly and keep the proper aspect ratio, you can read http://selbie.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/scale-crop-and-center-an-image-with-correct-aspect-ratio-in-html-and-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to make sure the entire background image fits into the div?

The [`background-size` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size).

> I know you can size it with CSS3 but i'm looking for a solution for older browsers.

There is no other standard way to scale a background image.

---

Older versions of Internet Explorer can be supported via the [non-standard `filter` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`AlphaImageLoader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms532853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
/* Untested */
background-image: url(images/someimage.png);
background-resize: cover;
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/someimage.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/someimage.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
```

---

Alternatively, as a hack, you could use an `<img>` element, and absolutely position it behind the content. This would be a *content* image though, so it wouldn't be a clean hack.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your div has id equal to "myid" .

picture used has as size 500x500

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/rhPDx/

```
div#myid{
   width: 200px;
    height:200px;

  background: url('http://px6.streetfire.net/0001/72/25/1952752_600.jpg') 
                0% 0% 
                no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;


}
```

Comment: That will *position* the image, not resize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by applying `background-size:100% 100%;` to your `div`

Hope it will help

Answer (score -1):

You cant resize ur image in backgound image attribute.

There's an other, tricky way to do this. Just place your background image in your div and add absolute position to it. Ofc ur div need to have a relative postion attribute.

After this you can resize ur image, simply with css2.